# Are return springs on a carburetor throttle mandatory or not?

Tags: faa-regulations, piston-engine, easa-regulations, aircraft-certification

In many GA aeroplanes throttle control is connected mechanically to the throttle of carburetor via a cable. I read in some AFMs that in case of a cable failure, return springs will open the throttle so an engine will be at full power.

Is it mandatory to have those springs installed (a certification requirement or something) or it is optional? I'm asking about EASA regulations, but a reference to FAA regulations will also be helpful.

Comment: Which AFMs?  I've never seen that myself.

Comment: e.g. Aero AT-3, PS-28 Cruiser

Comment: From the airplanes you mentioned, that's sounds like it's maybe an Eastern European practice.  I've never heard of any regulation requiring throttle springs in North America, but I can't speak for EASA requirements.

Comment: You might be interested in https://law.justia.com/cases/oregon/supreme-court/1978/577-p-2d-1322-6.html. As I remember (50 years ago now), Piper issued an AD requiring a spring be put on the carburetor. In the accident, what happened is that the engine quit when the carb heat control was pushed in to get full power.

Comment: @Terry Couldn't find an AD that requires a spring on Cherokees in the database.  That crash seems to be mostly about carb icing.

Comment: The FAA doesn't require it. Some carb manufacturers may have them but I've never seen them used. You can get return springs for Rotax engines but only for non-certified aircraft and then again only to prevent throttle creep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FAA doesn't require it, but some carburettor manufacturers may have them. You can get return springs for Rotax engines, but only for non-certified aircraft and then again only to prevent throttle creep